# Version controlled meta information such as tags and filters in EA

Tags: enterprise-architect

The goal is to have a fully version controlled EA model with the UML/SysML/... content aswell as metainformation like tags (inluding enum type specification) or configured filters.

Using the CVS-integration with SVN its easily possible to synchronize the general model data within the team. Tags can be defined by a developer as a enum with the valid values by adding the following snippet to *"UML Typed" -> "Tagged Values Types"*:

```
Type=Enum;
Values=A, B, C;
```

I expect EA to synchronize the Tags enum definition using the VCS once created or after the first usage. However, EA seems to only sync the tags that have been applied to model elements without any meta information like enum-definitions or descriptions. I can confirm that the defined tag gets saved inside the "local model"-File of the EA-Project and is not saved in some user-only directory.

One possible solution I found is using the "Export/Import Reference Data" function of EA that is described [here](https://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/14.0/modeling_tools/tagged_value_types.html) and to sync the data in a separate repository. It's a really clunky approach including several manual steps that can lead to faults - such as forgetting about exporting after a change of the tagged value types.

Is there a better solution that I just missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the version control integration you are storing *package* information into an XMI file and upload that to the version control system (SVN in your case).

The tagged values definition is **meta-** information that is *not* stored in that package, and thus not part of the XMI file that is uploaded to SVN.

The best way to deal with things like this is to add tagged values to stereotypes in a [UML profile](https://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/16.0/modeling_frameworks/umlprofiles_2.html), that is packaged into an [MDG file](https://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/16.0/modeling_frameworks/creatingmdgtechnologies.html).

MDG files can be considered as packaged meta-models. You can store the MDG file in your version control system as well, and instruct users to use the latest MDG file when using EA.

Comment: That's probably the right way. However, for something like my use-case that only needs some reference data to be shared, its more pragmatic (to me, someone that never created a MDG file) to do it using the Import/Export function I described in my question.